# array multiple filter and variable assignment at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following `forEach` statement:

```
reviews.forEach(review => {
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeThreeMonthsDate) {
        lastThreeMonths.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeSixMonthsDate) {
        lastSixMonths.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeOneYearDate) {
        lastYear.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeTwoYearsDate) {
        lastTwoYear.push(review);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to get the same result **with looping just one time** through the `reviews` list using `filter` or any new **ES6** functionality

Comment: But you are looping only one time, aren't you?

Comment: @Johnny yes, I just want to know is there a new cleaner way to do that

Comment: If performance is key then probably nothing cleaner.

Comment: If you have working code and want to improve it, you can post it on **https://codereview.stackexchange.com**. But, your code looks clean and easily understandable as it is

Comment: @adiga OP doesn't seem to be asking for a general code review, but rather for a *specific* outcome: get the same result by looping once using `filter` or similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It changes the output a little but, you could `reduce` to an object. instead of 4 separate variables.

```
const {
  lastThreeMonths,
  lastSixMonths,
  lastYear,
  lastTwoYear
} = reviews.reduce(
  (groups, review) => {
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeThreeMonthsDate) {
      groups.lastThreeMonths.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeSixMonthsDate) {
      groups.lastSixMonths.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeOneYearDate) {
      groups.lastYear.push(review);
    }
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeTwoYearsDate) {
      groups.lastTwoYear.push(review);
    }
  },
  { lastThreeMonths: [], lastSixMonths: [], lastYear: [], lastTwoYear: [] }
);
```

This is really similar to a `groupBy` function.

But I'd think about how this info is used. If it's for a view layer I would think about sorting and then using a `takeUntil` type function for flexibility. If you needed `lastWeek`, `lastDay` and more then the previous and original solutions could get unwieldy.

```
const takeUntil = (pred, list) =>
  list.reduce((taken, next) => (pred(next) ? taken.concat(next) : taken), []);
const sinceTwoDays = takeUntil(review => review.timestamp >= twoDaysAgo, reviews);
```

This way loops at minimum 2 times but it gives a lot of future flexibility. You can pass any date in and return it.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**. You also can make this function rather versatile by reducing to an array and (optionally) [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract each nested array as a separate variable. This way, you don't need to define each key name within the function. The result may or may not be considered "cleaner" depending on what your goals are, though. For example, see the `getReviewsSince()` function in the snippet below:

```js
// Don't mind these functions, they're just for the sake of a working example snippet
const writeLine = (() => {
  const preEl = document.querySelector('.js-pre')
  return (s = '') => preEl.textContent += `${s}\n`
})()

const writeArr = (name, arr) => {
  writeLine(name)
  arr.forEach(r => writeLine(JSON.stringify(r)))
  writeLine()
}

const getExampleReviews = () => {
  let i = 0
  return [
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1562166556565 },
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1514985756565 },
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1514995756565 },
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1562165556565 },
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1451837356565 },
    { id: i++, timestamp: 1451837356565 },
  ]
}

// ---

// Get an array - each element is a nested array for the matching timestamp
const getReviewsSince = (reviews, timestamps) =>
  reviews.reduce((arr, review) => {
    timestamps.forEach((ts, idx) => {
      if (review.timestamp >= ts) {
        arr[idx].push(review)
      }
    })
    return arr
  }, timestamps.map(() => []))

// Example usage of getReviewsSince() w/ destructuring
const reviews = getExampleReviews()
const [
  lastThreeMonths,
  lastSixMonths,
  lastYear,
  lastTwoYears,
] = getReviewsSince(reviews, [
  1562166556565,
  1546531756565,
  1514995756565,
  1451837356565,
])

// Output the results for us to see
writeArr('lastThreeMonths', lastThreeMonths)
writeArr('lastSixMonths', lastSixMonths)
writeArr('lastYear', lastYear)
writeArr('lastTwoYears', lastTwoYears)
```

```html
<pre class="js-pre"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to remove the if statements and make it more compact.

```
reviews.forEach(review => {
    review.timestamp >= beforeThreeMonthsDate && lastThreeMonths.push(review);
    review.timestamp >= beforeSixMonthsDate && lastSixMonths.push(review);
    review.timestamp >= beforeOneYearDate && lastYear.push(review);
    review.timestamp >= beforeTwoYearsDate && lastTwoYear.push(review);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is great but if you want cleaner i ocurred something like this:

```
let lastThreeMonths  = [];
let lastSixMonths    = [];
let lastYearMonths   = [];
let lastTwoYears     = [];

reviews.forEach(review => {
    if (review.timestamp >= beforeThreeMonthsDate) {
        lastThreeMonths = [...lastThreeMonths, review];
    }
    else if (review.timestamp >= beforeSixMonthsDate) {
        lastSixMonths = [...lastSixMonths, review];
    }
    else if (review.timestamp >= beforeOneYearDate) {
        lastYear = [...lastYear, review ];
    }
    else if (review.timestamp >= beforeTwoYearsDate) {
        lastTwoYear = [...lastTwoYear, review];
    }
});
```

You can check the docs of destructing assignment [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

Comment: How is creating new arrays in every loop better than pushing to existing array?

Comment: Its not better, it could be cleaner, it's just using an **ES6 feature** as the OP said so, and the destructing assignment isnt creating new arrays it is populating them. The docs are very clear. So why the downvote?

Comment: OP just wants to know if there are any better ways to do this with ES6. Not use ES6 just for the sake of it. And `[...lastTwoYear, review]` creates a new array. This answer is worse than what OP already has

Comment: Not sure why is this worse, can you elaborate?, as i can understand its doing the same thing, just using ES6 destructing assignment to populate the previously declared empty arrays, I've also haven't read the word **better** in the OP post, i understand that OP just want other solutions involving ES6,

Comment: `[...lastTwoYear, review]` creates a **new** array with all the elements of `lastTwoYear` along with `review`.

Answer (score -3):

Since your code already have only one loop, I am not sure what you need for "with looping just one time".

With the filter, you can do this.

```
lastThreeMonths = reviews.filter(review => review.timestamp >= beforeThreeMonthsDate);
lastSixMonths = reviews.filter(review => review.timestamp >= beforeSixMonthsDate);
lastYear = reviews.filter(review => review.timestamp >= beforeOneYearDate);
lastTwoYear = reviews.filter(review => review.timestamp >= beforeTwoYearsDate);
```

Comment: This loops the array 4 times. OP has mentioned *"with looping just one time"* in bold.